# React Native set variable in another js file

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i got a global style js file with a boolean to control if i use lightmode or darkmode.
How can i set this boolean via a button inside a different js file?

How can i set StylingVars.darkmode to true (or false) in the StylingVars.js file?

```
ProfileScreen = () => {
  const [darkmode, setDarkmode] = useState(StylingVars.darkmode);
  const ToggleDarkmode = () => {
    setDarkmode(!darkmode);
  }
  useEffect( () => {
    console.log(darkmode)
  }, [darkmode]);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: StylingVars.darkmode === false ? StylingVars.lightmodeBackground : StylingVars.darkmodeBackground}}>
      <StatusBar style={StylingVars.darkmode === false ? 'dark' : 'light'}/>
      <Button title='DarkMode' onPress={() => {
        ToggleDarkmode()
      }}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

This is what i currently have, but useState does not overwrite my boolean in the other file it rather creates a new var with the initial value (if i'm not wrong here).

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably want to use a state management library - you might have heard of Redux or Mobx. I'd recommend Zustand for state management.